# How to get all total for all rows across all pages in a UI-GRID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I am trying to display the total sum for a column in my UI-GRID. the problem is that I display 10 rows per page and the ui-grid footer only calculates the total sum for the the rows per page. How do I enable the ui-grid to calculate the total for all the rows in the UI-GRID

I have a created a plunker example to show my issue:
http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Gjpt8tw4JpDzl1lG?preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom sum function and pass it in as the aggregationType in your grid options columnDefs.

For example here is a function for the over all sum for address street numbers:

```
var addOverAllTotalAddress = function() {
  var sum = 0;
   $scope.gridOptions.data.forEach(function(item){
    sum = sum + item.address.street;
  });
  return sum;
};
```

Here is a working plunker: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ITkXFmIdD2ZJh1dS?preview

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks AAV! :)